# Problemas da Conexão entre o Entity Framework e a Base de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, conexão

Ao executar a minha aplicação estou encontrando o seguinte erro na hora de carregar os dados através do `Entity Framework`.

Quando ele é executado observo que é chamada a seguinte ***string de conexão***:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nela observo que esta sendo carregado um usuário e senha diferentes do que informo no `Web.config` (que são os que efetivamente funcionam para a conexão com o banco).

Abaixo a conexão correta:

> `data source=desenv-srvsql\sqlclust01;initial catalog=dbBANPARA_SGDTV;user
>   id=ntconsult;password=12345;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"`

Já revisei todas as minhas classes e não encontrei de onde esta sendo tirada a informação passada na primeira imagem. Gostaria de ajuda para a questão e se possível conseguir passar a informação correta para a aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se não existem duas strings de conexão no seu arquivo web.config e verifique na classe de criação de contexto se você está utilizando a connection string correta.

Comment: Já olhei o web.config e esta tudo correto. Onde ficaria essa classe de criação de contexto?

Comment: @RodneyVictor procure por uma classe que herde de DbContext. Não sei como sua aplicação está configurada, mas pode ser que você não tenha criado uma classe de contexto. Boa sorte.